# Shared Office Script Can Only Be Edited By Owner

Tags: office-scripts

Office scripts team, wherever ye might be. I'm trying to get my organization to switch over from VBA scripts to office scripts but there is a snag. Only the owner of an office a script can edit / add it to a spreadsheet. If I try to open a script on a shared folder from someone else, I can pick the file, but then it just either silently fails or throws a not found error when I try to add it to a spreadsheet. It only works to add a office to a spreadsheet if the user logged into excel is the same as the one who owns the onedrive drive.

It does work if the script is stored in a sharepoint site, however, the script I'm making needs to make a fetch call which does not work on a sharepoint site according to the docs.

We could have everyone just write their own scripts and save them in their personal drives, but if that person ever leaves, those scripts would be removed from all the spreadsheets they were bound to. This could be in the thousands.

Essentially, I need to login to a server via remote desktop as a service account to add office scripts to spreadsheets if I want to be able to make sure the link to the spreadsheet isn't broken some day.

I've tried adding a script to shared folder with multiple people. Each time I cannot add the script to the spreadsheet. I usually tested with the default script that is made. So, for example, person A has the script in their folder that is shared with person B, person B cannot add that script to a spreadsheet even though they have access to it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you're running into this issue - unfortunately, external calls indeed don't work in SharePoint scripts as a security measure. If I'm understanding correctly, you would like to 1. have a script stored in the OneDrive of a service account, 2. allow any user with access to the script file to attach the script to a workbook? Could I ask for more details about #2? We might be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: Whoa! It looks like I'll need to tweak some of my email settings on my profile. I just got an email from Stackoverflow today! The way you have described it is correct. I'll use an example to describe it further. We have an office 365 account under the name support. I've created a shared folder within support's OneDrive. Ideally I would be able to share that folder with an employee named Stacy. Stacy could then save her office script that she is developing in that folder and attach it to a spreadsheet. Now, if Stacy retires, that script doesn't get deleted when her account is closed down.

Comment: The reason we are using external calls is that we have a locally running API. That API is configured to disable CORS errors, However, we only expose that API to the internal network. Since the script itself runs on the person executing it's computer it works. We also have a token in the spreadsheet itself for authentication. It's essentially as secure as just having that file on the network. This opens up the potential for implementing all the things office scripts can't do out of the box. Honestly how office scripts executes is brilliant, you get all the security of the browser built in.

Comment: I believe that if your scripts have external calls, the best option for you right now would be to ask any employees who want to develop/attach scripts to log into a service account to do so (i.e., the service account should own all the scripts). Sorry that I can't offer a better solution - let me know if you have any further questions or feedback here!

Comment: That's the conclusion we came to. Not really possible to share an account with everyone in the company, especially since deleting a script file would cause everything to break. We just upload scripts on their behalf. I can understand why it is set up this way. I wish that this could at least be accomplished with power automate. There is no way to trigger a power automate flow from office scripts.